# Regex double forward slash in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

I would like to regex the one or more `//` after `https://` in `https://website.com.au//my-account//` in Google Analytics Custom reports filters.

I have found that this regex should work normally but not in GA.

Regex: `(?<!:)\/\/`

Required solution:
What I need to find are the `//` after `.com.au` and  `my-account` and not the one after `https:`.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't you mean `(?!:)\/\/`

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the original post, I need the second and third `//` and if any others. But GA does not run this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to match any char except a `:` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and then use a capturing group to match the `//`

```
[^:](\/\/)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vLcdr3/1)

To not find the match after https:// you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) matching what you want and capture in a group what you don't want

```
https?:\/\/|(\/\/)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DgAXUD/1)